# Must the sequence $X_n$ converge to $0$ in probability?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of random variables with

$\lim_{n\to +\infty} E[|X_n|] = 0$.

Is it correct or wrong that the sequence $X_n$ must converge to $0$ in probability?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it follows from Chebyshev's inequality. For every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have
$$\mathrm{Pr}(|X_n| > \varepsilon) \leq {\mathbb E}[|X_n|]/\varepsilon \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as a consequence of the inequality $\mu\{|X_n|\geqslant \varepsilon\}\leqslant\frac 1{\varepsilon}E[|X_n|]$ for each positive $\varepsilon$.